# Cannot change baud rate on usb serial device

Tags: ubuntu, usb, serial-port

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 from 10.04. Under 10.04 I had no trouble using usbserial driver to connect to a device through the serial port. After the upgrade *usually* I cannot reset the baud rate: it is initialized to 9600, but my device needs 115200. When I try to reset the speed I get:

```
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
-brkint -imaxbel
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
stty: /dev/ttyUSB0: unable to perform all requested operations
$ sudo setserial -av /dev/ttyUSB0
Cannot get serial info: Invalid argument
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUS*
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Nov 26 10:21 /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 1 Nov 26 10:21 /dev/ttyUSB1
```

The oddest thing is that I have gotten this to work on occasion. The first time I rebooted the system, and it worked. After a shutdown it had the same problem and rebooting did not work, but reloading the driver did. Unfortunately this has not worked since:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r usbserial
$ sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0403 product=0x6001
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
stty: /dev/ttyUSB0: unable to perform all requested operations
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the solution to this, in case anyone googles it in the future. My 10.04 did not load usbserial by default, so I had to do it with `modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0403 product=0x6001`, which I added to `/etc/modules`. After I upgraded, my 12.04 loads the `ftdi_sio` driver by default, which is for the embedded device I am using. I didn't change my `/etc/modules` back, so `usbserial` was being loaded too, and probably causing some sort of conflict. I removed `usbserial` from `/etc/modules` and rebooted, and it worked.

If I were really confident in this solution I would confirm it by rebooting my machine again and seeing if the serial port came up properly - but I would feel pretty silly if I rebooted and lost the connection, since I do need to get work done while I have it.

Answer (score 1):

USB to serial devices like the Prolific or FTDI series don't follow any official specification.  Instead, they use two bulk endpoints (one for output, one for input) with specific vendor-specific control messages used to configure things like baudrate.  Thus, it's not too much of a surprise if something like the generic `usbserial` driver has trouble setting baudrates or doing other configuration tasks on a FTDI chip.  As you noticed, using `ftdi_sio` will work much better.

Even 10.04 should be loading `ftdi_sio` by default, as `ftdi_sio` has been hardcoded to handle 4003:6001 (FT232) devices for nearly as long as Ubuntu has existed.  My guess is that you were loading two drivers that were both registered to handle 4003:6001 -- one by design, one due to your module parameters.  Changing your kernel or even the phase of the moon could mean that one happens to get loaded before the other -- and if `usbserial` gets loaded first, you will not be able to set baudrate.  You should remove your manual `usbserial` configuration, and let `ftdi_sio` handle the device.  It will work on both 10.04 and 12.04.